# Is it possible to exclude a target from a NAnt build?

Tags: nant

I am looking for a way to tell NAnt *not* to execute a specified target. I've not found anything online so I'm not hopeful but perhaps the good people of SO can help.

The situation is: we have targets `A, B, C, D,` as well as an overall target `T` that calls all the others. `A` is independent of the others so is not really necessary; consider it a sort of an expensive sanity check.

I want to be able to run `T` and but exclude `A` - so it would only run `B, C, D`.
Is this possible, or do I have to declare a new target to specifically run those jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NotAgain's answer is useful if the target to be excluded is at the beginning or the end of the chain, but it does involve setting up a new target, or at least editing the existing one.

The best solution I've found so far is to use the conditional logic expressions.
Example:

```
<property name="runThis" value="true" />
<target name="runIfPropTrue" if="${runThis}">
    <exec program="test.bat" />
</target>
```

This way you can set up any targets you may wish to exclude and switch them on and off by editing the property or by passing it in as a parameter instead.
I assume you can use the `unless` expression just as easily but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking in very simple way. You situation might be different.

I would have made T depend on B, C and D only.

When A is also needed I can call it in form of:

NAnt buildfile:Blah.build A T

Comment: This would work but would not help if I wanted to exclude B or C. I've found a partial solution, posting an answer soon.